# conditional formatting with vlookup

Tags: excel

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a spread sheet for products that have different expiry dates. Some products have a 12 month shelf life and others longer. The cells of those that are good, close to expiry (say 3 months off expiring) and have expired coloured different.

Is there a way of doing this, possibly using a vlookup table to find product then apply the conditional formatting using the dates in the spreadsheet?

see example spreadsheet
thanks

[conditional formatting](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11o63J1bZTws3hOW5i6Pe0b80PJA2GZiqDWfXqIYiCls/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would be good if you colored the cells in your sample the way you mean to get them as a result.

Comment: thank you for replying, particular colours are not important, i'm more interested if there is way of doing this

Comment: You'll need something like this `=(C3-B3)/365.25*12>VALUE(LEFT(VLOOKUP(A3,$F$3:$G$8,2,0),2))`. 
I'd recommend instead using a helper column called "Months until expired" and leveraging off that for your conditional formatting.    Also if you change the cell formatting of G3:G7 to `"months "0` you can directly use the number in these cells directly; this is why the formula above uses the  `VALUE` formula.